# Computing $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_t(x) g(x) dx$ for $f_t(x) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{t}} e^{-t x^2}$, and bdd $g(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f_t(x) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{t}} e^{-t x^2}$ and $g(x)$ be bounded function on $\mathbb{R}$.

I want to compute and proves the limit,  $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_t(x) g(x) dx$.

For specific bounded function as $g(x)=e^{-\alpha x}$, I obtain the limit is nothing but $1$[by making perfect square and using Gaussian integral formula with taking limit I obtain its limit is $1$], but I am not sure how to extend this in general bounded function.

Comment: Do you really want the limit as $t\to \infty$? The limit as $t\to 0$ is more interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g(x)$ be a bounded function over $\mathbb{R}$, i.e., $|g(x)| \leq M$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and for some constant $M \geq 0$. Let $t$ be a parameter over the positive reals; observe that we have the inequality

$$\left|\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_t(x)g(x)\, dx\right|\leq \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{t}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-tx^2}|g(x)| \, dx\leq M\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{t}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-tx^2} \, dx,$$
for which the latter integral is a Gaussian integral with value $\displaystyle \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{t}}$. Applying limits, we have
$$ \left|\lim_{t \to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_t(x)g(x)\, dx\right| \leq \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{M\pi}{t} \to 0,$$
so that, by the Squeeze Theorem, our integral is $0$.